# NullPointerException attempt to invoke method.GoogleMap.setMapType(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a google map in a fragment to draw polygon in my application. and menu on actionbar from that i able to change my map view type. also one FAB on google map fragment to change the type of map to satellite view.but when i click on FAB my app crash and throwing

**NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setFilter(com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter)' on a null object reference.**

here is my code in onCreateView method:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mapViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MapViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    FloatingActionButton fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        }
    });
```

and this is code which work in menuItem :

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.satellite:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.Draw:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your GoogleMap instance `mMap` has been initialized before you call `setMapType` on it. Try doing a quick check first:

```
if (mMap != null) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
}
```

And most importantly, double check that you're initializing your map correctly using the [`getMapAsync`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#public-void-getmapasync-onmapreadycallback-callback) and [`onMapReady`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback#public-abstract-void-onmapready-googlemap-googlemap) methods as per Google's [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start).

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!